# PHP hyperlink transfer SQL ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html

I am working on a personal project to keep track of my flights in a simulator game. I have a database setup, one for the flight itself (with a unique ID) and one for a detailed view of that flight - which matches up to the ID of the flight table accordingly.

I am trying to display my information using PHP, and have successfully made a page using PHP to echo the basic flights using this code:

PHP:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Flights;';
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Date Flown </th> <th> Departure Airport </th> <th> Arrival Airport </th> <th> Flight Time </th> <th> Aircraft </th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Departure Airport']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Arrival Airport']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Time Taken']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Aircraft']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="/detailedFlight.php<?= $ID ?>"> View Detailed </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</table>
```

This works fine.

However, I want to see a detailed view of my flights when I click 'View Detailed', and this is the code I currently have for it:

PHP:

```
$flightID = $_GET['ID'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM DetailedFlights WHERE ID = '.intval($flightID);
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Filed Altitude </th> <th> Filed Speed </th> <th> Actual Flown </th> <th> Route </th> <th> SID </th> <th> Departing Runway </th> <th> STAR </th> <th> Arrival Runway </th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Filed Altitude']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Filed Speed']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Actual Flown']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Route']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['SID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Depart Runway']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['STAR']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Arrival Runway']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</table>
```

The problem is, when clicked on view detailed, it always returns the detail for the flight stored under entry number '0'. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, this is what needed to be changed:

`<td><a href="/detailedFlight.php?ID=<?= $row['ID'] ?>"> View Detailed &#8594; </a></td>`

Comment: well to be fair that was one of my suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1):

basicly your passing the id incorrectly

```
 <td><a href="/detailedFlight.php?ID=<?= $ID ?>"> View Detailed </a></td>
```

and then

```
$flightID = $_GET['ID'];
```

Comment: It still does not work with your improved code, same problem exists

Comment: in detailedFlight.php if you hard code the id, do you ge the correct data?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM DetailedFlights WHERE ID = 2'; does return the correct data.

Comment: and the url shows as `detailedFlight.php?ID=2` ? should `$ID` be `$row['ID'];` or `$row['id'];` ?

Comment: When clicked via the view details link then the url is just `http://karankharay.net23.net/detailedFlight.php?ID=` i don't think the ID is being passed correctly?

Comment: ok so the id is not being populated, did you try `$row['ID'];` or `$row['id'];` ?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by this please. Here is more php `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM DetailedFlights WHERE ID = :flight;';

 $query = $dbhandle->prepare($sql);
 if ( $query->execute(array(':flight' => $flightID)) === FALSE ) {
  die('Error Running Query: ' . implode($query->errorInfo(), ' '));
 }

 $results = $query->fetchAll();
?>` this is for the detailedFlight.php part